# Physical meaning of RG potential

Tags: quantum-field-theory, potential, renormalization

In the concept of RG theory, one has for example a theory with a renormalised coupling $\lambda$ and its respective $\beta$-function 
$$\beta_{\lambda}=\mu_{}\frac{d\lambda}{d\mu}\hspace{0.1cm},$$
where $\mu$ is the mass parameter introduced via the dimensional regularisation.

One can then define the RG potential $U(\lambda)$ from the relation 
$$\beta_{\lambda}\equiv \frac{d U(\lambda)}{d\lambda}\hspace{0.2cm},$$
the extrema of which correspond to the theory's fixed points.

It is also known that minima and maxima of $U(\lambda)$ correspond to IR and UV stable fixed points, respectivelly. Is there a physical explanation why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\beta$ tells you how $\lambda$ changes as $\mu$ increases. You are going to the UV as $\mu$ increases. If you want to go to the IR, flip the sign of $\beta$.

At the extrema of $U$, $\beta=\partial_\lambda U = 0$, that's why they are fixed points.

At the maxima the second derivative of $U$ is negative. $\partial_\lambda \beta < 0$, so if you are a slightly greater than the fixed point $\lambda$ you decrease as you go to the UV, and if you are slightly less you increase. So it is stable in the UV.

For minima the sign is flipped so it is unstable in the UV, but stable in the IR.